# Add class based on a condiiton in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements

I want to add classes based on a condition in angularJs, I am following below method and it is working fine, Is there any best practice?

```
<div ng-if="client.status != 2" class="list-primary">
                    <span class="pull-right amount">{{client.receivables|number:2}}</span>
                    <div class="name">{{client.name}}</div>
                </div>


                <div ng-if="client.status == 2" class="list-primary text-muted">
                    <span class="pull-right amount">{{client.receivables|number:2}}</span>
                    <div class="name">{{client.name}}</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: use `ng-class` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` for this:

```
<!-- apply class 'text-muted' when client.status == 2 -->
<div class="list-primary" ng-class="{ 'text-muted': client.status == 2 }">
    <span class="pull-right amount">{{client.receivables|number:2}}</span>
    <div class="name">{{client.name}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In angular **1.1.5+** you can use `javascript` ternary operator.

```
<div ng-class="client.status == 2 ? 'text-muted' : 'other-class'" class="list-primary ">
     <span class="pull-right amount">{{client.receivables|number:2}}</span>
     <div class="name">{{client.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `ng-class` which is provided in AngularJS. Documentation here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass